# Netbeans: Compile/Build/Jar a class in a Project

Tags: netbeans, jar

In the course of working on a project, I've made a handy class that I would like to jar up and distribute.

How does one generate the jar file for a single class in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

You can simple Clean and Build(Shift+F11) that project where you have the jar file.

Don't forget to go Project Properties-> Run and in "Main Class" choose that main class.